# Vim/YCM - change warning highlight color

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I'm using the YouCompleteMe plugin for vim on Mac OSX, primarily for C++. Right now it highlights both errors and warnings in a pinkish color, but I want warnings to be highlighted in a yellow-ish sort of color. I think I'm supposed to place these 3 lines somewhere:

```
highlight YcmWarningLine guibg=#ffffcc
highlight YcmWarningSign guibg=#ffffcc
highlight YcmWarningSection guibg=#ffffcc
```

Problem is I don't know which file to place them in. Where do I place them, and in general am I going about this the right way?

Comment: Read [`:help mysyntaxfile-add`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#mysyntaxfile-add).

Answer (score 1):

*Highlight groups* are global, only the syntax definitions that parse individual filetypes are specific. Syntax scripts canonically use `:hi def` to avoid overriding group definitions already customized by the user. Therefore, it is sufficient to place those commands into your `~/.vimrc`, but *after* any `:colorscheme` command.

If you switch colorschemes on the fly (without restarting Vim), you'll notice that your custom highlightings will disappear. To keep them, you additionally need to reinstall them. Duplicate the `:hi` commands and prepend

```
:autocmd ColorScheme *
```

to them.

Answer (score 1):

Those and other vim configuration settings should be added to your `~/.vimrc`.